# adding items to dataGrid, datagrid.item.add confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `dataGrid` with two columns in it, and I want to add rows to them in my .cs file with `dataGrid1.Items.Add()`.

I know it takes in an object, but how does it determine which value in the object to take? It feels messy to just create a generic class just to put new rows into the dataGrid, is there another way to do this?

So below I have a generic object, how do I make it so that `.Add` will add in the name and age into dataGrid1?

generic class:

```
namespace myApp
{
public class generic
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public generic(string n, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

}
}
```

I've tried `dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Item("Ann", 21))`; //show a row of empty cells. I just cant wrap my head around how this works

edit for more info:

in my .xaml

`<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />`

in my cs file:

```
        DataGridTextColumn nameColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
        DataGridTextColumn ageColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();

        nameColumn.Header = "name";
        nameColumn.Binding = new Binding("name");
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

        ageColumn.Header = "age";
        ageColumn.Binding = new Binding("age");
        dataGrid1.Columns.Add(ageColumn);
```

Then I have a click function, that whenever clicked will generate a new name and age, then add it to dataGrid1

Comment: If all the items in the DataGrid are the same type, and it has AutoGenerateColumns turned on, it'll generate columns based on their public properties that have a `getter`: `public String Name { get; protected set; }`, for example. Do the same with Age. Then it'd help if you could share your XAML for the DataGrid so we can see how you're defining the rows.

Comment: You should be populating the DataGrid with an ObservableCollection belonging to a viewmodel, instead of writing all this stuff in the code behind, but we can take this one step at a time.

Comment: I edited my post for more info. does it make more sense? thanks.
Im having some trouble understanding the `populate datagrid with observablecollection belonging to a viewmodel`.

Comment: Is `productColumn` supposed to be `nameColumn`? I'd advise you to define the columns in XAML. Anyway, try defining the properties on `generic` as I suggested in my first comment, except make them lowercase if you want to use lowercase names: `public String name { get; protected set; }`. This stuff is all case sensitive. Then see what happens.

Comment: yea it is my bad. Ok I'll give it a try now

Comment: ok so after changing my generic to:    

`public class generic
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }`
then I use it `dataGrid1.Items.Add(new generic { Name= "Ann", Age= "1"});`

It works but it feels weird to create a class like this just to input something into the grid. There's no other way to structure this?

Comment: Glad to hear that did it. Let me put that in an answer you can mark correct. This is the only reasonable way to do it. Storing your data in the UI is a really bad way to write an application. Every single thing you do after you make that decision will be two to ten times as hard as it needs to be. Trust me. It's like using the trunk of your car to store all your clean clothes. Do you want to run out in the street naked to get dressed after a shower? No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `DataGrid` will generate a column for each public property in the data item class (`AutoGenerateColumns` should be `true`; if not, make it so in the XAML), so you need to add public properties accordingly. You should be defining your columns in XAML and creating a main viewmodel with an `ObservableCollection` of this `generic` class, instead of adding them to `Items` by hand, but Rome wasn't built in a day.

This version of your class should work:

```
public class generic
{
    public generic(string n, int a)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Your intuition about this being "messy" is natural for somebody relatively new to the field, but it's mistaken. What's "messy" is trying to store all your data in user interface controls. When you write code that way, everything rapidly turns into a nightmare. Everything you need to do involves writing multiple lines of semi-redundant code to get to your data items and do anything with them. That way of doing things is like storing everything you own in the trunk of your car, then running out naked in the street after a shower to get dressed or when you need a clean fork. And naturally, all your logic is copied and pasted from one event handler to the next, then slightly modified.

I used to call that "RAD Syndrome" back in the 90s when "Rapid Application Development" was the hot buzzword for any environment like VB or Delphi. WPF does not encourage you to write code that way, and that's actually for the best. Think of it this way: Structured programming seemed a bit arbitrary to me on my first encounter with it when I was a kid in the 80s, and object oriented programming seemed weirdly arbitrary later on. But after I got used to working with them, I found them tremendously useful. Same kind of deal with this MVVM stuff.